# Insertion to std::list<std::vector<int>> failed when using initializer list as the value?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a C++ snippet that looks like this:

```cpp
  std::list<std::vector<int>> lv;
  lv.push_back({});
  std::cout << lv.size() << std::endl; // "1"

  lv.insert(lv.end(), {});  // Oops!
  // lv.insert(lv.end(), std::vector<int>());  // OK
  std::cout << lv.size() << std::endl; // Still got "1", but why?
```

As you can see, when using `{}` to create a default `std::vector<int>`, the insertion didn't happen at all. While I know that there are lots of subtleties when using C++'s initializer list,  I wonder what is the problem in this example?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you already figured this out, but one workaround would be `lv.insert(lv.end(), {{}});`.

Comment: Yep, i missed the last overload in the doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overload resolution for the

> ```
> lv.insert(lv.end(), {});  // Oops!
> ```

call will resolve (formally, chosen as the *best viable function* as per [[over.ics.rank]/3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.1)) to the following `std::list<>::insert` overload [extract from [`std::list<>::insert` at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert), **emphasis** mine]:

> ```
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
> ```
>
> inserts elements **from initializer list** ilist before pos.

But as the initializer list is empty, there are no elements *from* it to be inserted.

---

You could likewise invoke the same `insert` overload with a nested list initialization within the list initialization,

```
lv.insert(lv.end(), {{}});  // Size is now 2.
```

such that the innermost list initialization will resolve to (as per [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list#1)) the [`std::initializer_list` constructor of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> ```
> vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
>         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

in so inserting a single element of type `std::vector<int>`, specifically an an empty such vector, into the `std::list<std::vector<int>>` object.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back), the `{}` argument is deduced to be the element type of the list, so a single `vector` gets inserted into the list.

When you call [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert), you are using the initializer list overload, and since the initializer list is empty, no elements get added to the list.